# Format of the initialization string does not conform to to specification starting at index 0

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, enterprise-library

I am using Microsoft Enterprise Lip I I have this method to Insert resource in the website 
I get this error down  i don't think it is permission problem and really i don't know how to solve it.by the way I test the connectionStrings and it work fine

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="SiteSqlServer"
      connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=databaseName;User ID=sa;Password=***"/>
  </connectionStrings>

 public static int Insert(Resoursce r)
        {
            Database objDB = new SqlDatabase("SiteSqlServer");
            int val = 0;
            using (DbCommand cmd = objDB.GetStoredProcCommand("InsertResoursce"))
            {
                //  OutParameter
                objDB.AddOutParameter(cmd,"@OutResoursceID",DbType.Int32,int.MaxValue);

                //  iNParameter
                objDB.AddInParameter(cmd, "@ModuleId", DbType.Int32, r.ModuleId);
                objDB.AddInParameter(cmd, "@Summary", DbType.StringFixedLength, r.Summary);
                objDB.AddInParameter(cmd, "@PageId", DbType.StringFixedLength, r.PageID);
                objDB.AddInParameter(cmd, "@TypeId", DbType.Int32, r.TypeID);
                objDB.AddInParameter(cmd, "@UserID", DbType.Guid, r.UserID);
                objDB.AddInParameter(cmd, "@Enabled", DbType.Boolean, r.Enabled);
                objDB.AddInParameter(cmd, "@SafetyAlert", DbType.Boolean, r.SafetyAlert);
                objDB.AddInParameter(cmd, "@SaftyAlertText", DbType.StringFixedLength, r.SafetyAlertText);


                try
                {
                     val = objDB.ExecuteNonQuery(cmd);
                     if (val == 1)
                     {
                         return Convert.ToInt32(objDB.GetParameterValue(cmd, "@OutResoursceID"));
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         return -1;
                     }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {


                    throw ex;
                } 

            }
```

> System.ArgumentException was caught   HResult=-2147024809
>   Message=Format of the initialization string does not conform to
>   specification starting at index 0.   Source=System.Data   StackTrace:
>          at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.GetKeyValuePair(String
>   connectionString, Int32 currentPosition, StringBuilder buffer, Boolean
>   useOdbcRules, String& keyname, String& keyvalue)
>          at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Hashtable
>   parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Hashtable
>   synonyms, Boolean firstKey)
>          at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean useOdbcRules)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString..ctor(String connectionString)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnectionOptions(String
>   connectionString, DbConnectionOptions previous)
>          at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnectionPoolGroup(DbConnectionPoolKey
>   key, DbConnectionPoolGroupOptions poolOptions, DbConnectionOptions&
>   userConnectionOptions)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ConnectionString_Set(DbConnectionPoolKey
>   key)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value)
>          at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database.CreateConnection()
>          at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database.GetNewOpenConnection()
>          at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database.GetWrappedConnection()
>          at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database.GetOpenConnection()
>          at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database.ExecuteNonQuery(DbCommand
>   command)
>          at Christoc.Modules.ResourceModule.App_Code.BOL.Resoursce.Insert(Resoursce
>   r) in
>   c:\inetpub\wwwroot\ideaPark\DesktopModules\ResourceModule\App_Code\BOL\Resoursce.cs:line
>   54   InnerException:

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This usually means your connection string isn't any good. If you look at the stack trace, you'll notice that this is failing when trying to interpret your connection string.

Check your connection string to make sure it is correct - or post it here for help (but without any sensitive information such as passwords ;) )

**UPDATE**

According to the [SqlDatabase documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb747545%28v=pandp.31%29.aspx) the SqlDatabase class takes a connection string, not a key to the connection string configuration.

So

```
new SqlDatabase("SiteSqlServer");
```

Should be

```
var connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SiteSqlServer"];

Database objDB = new SqlDatabase(connection.ConnectionString);
```

(I have omitted any defensive code here for brevity)

Answer (score -1):

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\KAMRAN RIYAZ\Desktop\Web Tech Lab Practice\ASP.NET\P21SQLoperations\P21SQLoperations\stu.mdf");

Above connection string worked for me.