# Convert sql select result to c# object

Tags: c#, sql, object

i want to create a c# object dynamically with data from sql select query

Query result example:

```
Percentage  Way

    47.64   DPAD_UP
    35.20   DPAD_DOWN
    8.67    LEFT_RIGHT_MENU
    5.54    MENU
    2.88    MENU_KRYESORE
    0.06    EPG_CLICK
```

from this query i want to create te following object:

```
data = new object[] { 
    new object[] { "DPAD_UP", 47.64 }, 
    new object[] { "DPAD_DOWN", 35.20 }, 
    new object[] { "LEFT_RIGHT_MENU", 8.67 },
    new object[] { "MENU", 5.54 }, 
    new object[] { "MENU_KRYESORE", 2.88 }, 
    new object[] { "EPG_CLICK", 0.06 } 
}
```

How to do this?

Comment: google Linq and Entity Framework. Entity Framework automatically turns your SQL objects into C# objects.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please try something on your own and if you are stuck somewhere than kindly let us know. We would be happy to help you.

Comment: Take a look at [Expando Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: If you are immediately using this object, you can use anonymous types.

Comment: Have a look at Dapper: https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for something like that? Just *direct reading* (I've assumed that you use MS SQL DBMS)

```
      List<Object[]> results = new List<Object[]>();

      using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Your connection String")) {
        conn.Open();

        using (SqlCommand query = new SqlCommand("your query", conn)) {
          //TODO: May be you have parameters - assign them here...

          using (var reader = query.ExecuteReader()) {
            while (reader.Read()) {
              results.Add(new Object[] {reader.GetValue(0), reader.GetValue(1)});
            }
          }
        }
      }

      data = results.ToArray();
```

Comment: I m getting this error
An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.

Comment: @Maria Agaci: Check your connection string. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16203376/format-of-the-initialization-string-does-not-conform-to-to-specification-startin