# Simplemembership error with sql azure. when publish to azure website

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, azure

> Exception Details

`System.ArgumentException: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.`

> Source Error:

```
 An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
```

> ArgumentException:

```
Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.
```

this is my connection strings:

```
<add name="OffOnProfiles" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="
    Server=tcp:xeriqb7gbj.database.windows.net,1433;
    Database=OffOnProfiles;
    User ID=OffOn@xeriqb7gbj;
    Password=*******;
    Trusted_Connection=False;
    Encrypt=True;
    Connection Timeout=30;"/>

<add name="OffOnStore" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="
    Server=tcp:xeriqb7gbj.database.windows.net,1433;
    Database=OffOnStore;
    User ID=OffOn@xeriqb7gbj;
    Password=*******;
    Trusted_Connection=False;
    Encrypt=True;
    Connection Timeout=30;"/>
```

[See full error here](http://offonstoreweb.azurewebsites.net/)

Comment: Did you deploy the necessary ASP.Net membership schema bits to your Azure SQL Database? Based on experience I would suggest this isn't specifically an Azure problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16203376/format-of-the-initialization-string-does-not-conform-to-to-specification-startin

Comment: @SimonW I got it to work, it were problems with the connections strings in my InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute.cs. Do i need to mark this solved or? new to stackoverflow..